# Order DB result according specific list

Tags: python-3.x, django-database

I need to display multiple rows (from a db query) according to the most occurence of one specific field. It seems that something like that is possible to handle with SQL windowing which I unfortunately can't use.

Thus, I query the db to count the occurence of that field and order the occurence value.
So I get a list which could look like:

```py
a = [504, 105, 494, 493, 439]
```

The second result which should be orered according to that list looks like:

```py
b = [{'id': 3141, 'nr': 'T003745', 'storage': 'S000108', 'storage_id': 105}, 
{'id': 3140, 'nr': 'T003744', 'storage': 'S000108', 'storage_id': 105}, 
{'id': 3238, 'nr': 'T002720', 'storage': 'S001662', 'storage_id': 439}, 
{'id': 2091, 'nr': 'T002887', 'storage': 'S002268', 'storage_id': 493}, 
{'id': 2109, 'nr': 'T002924', 'storage': 'S002267', 'storage_id': 494}, 
{'id': 2103, 'nr': 'T002911', 'storage': 'S002267', 'storage_id': 494}, 
{'id': 2266, 'nr': 'T003012', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504}, 
{'id': 2267, 'nr': 'T002990', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504}, 
{'id': 2253, 'nr': 'T003066', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504}, 
{'id': 2258, 'nr': 'T003038', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504}]
```

What I need now is a ordered list b according the storage_id sequence in a.

Result should look like:

```py
c = [{'id': 2266, 'nr': 'T003012', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504}, 
{'id': 2267, 'nr': 'T002990', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504}, 
{'id': 2253, 'nr': 'T003066', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504}, 
{'id': 2258, 'nr': 'T003038', 'storage': 'S002278', 'storage_id': 504},
{'id': 3141, 'nr': 'T003745', 'storage': 'S000108', 'storage_id': 105}, 
{'id': 3140, 'nr': 'T003744', 'storage': 'S000108', 'storage_id': 105},
{'id': 2109, 'nr': 'T002924', 'storage': 'S002267', 'storage_id': 494}, 
{'id': 2103, 'nr': 'T002911', 'storage': 'S002267', 'storage_id': 494},
{'id': 2091, 'nr': 'T002887', 'storage': 'S002268', 'storage_id': 493}, 
{'id': 3238, 'nr': 'T002720', 'storage': 'S001662', 'storage_id': 439}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem in the meantime using windowing function from PostgreSQL.

```
Tool.objects.filter(tooltype_id__in=setupline
    .get_needed_toolytpe_ids())
    .filter(checked_in=True)
    .select_related('storage')
    .select_related('tooltype')
    .order_by('storage')
    .annotate(
        sum_tools=Window(expression=Count('id'),
        partition_by=F('storage_id'),)
    )
    .order_by('-sum_tools', Length('tooltype__name'))
```

But i'd still like to know how if there exists a smart and short function for that without windowing.